# Git Deployment Succeeds But No Changes

Tags: asp.net, git, azure

I found myself in the weirdest situation here. I have been deploying to Azure via Git for a while now with no issues. However, I just pushed a fairly large set of changes to Azure got no error but nothing changed...

Tried to push again got "Everything up to date"

So, I logged into the Azure management console and looked under deployments and sure enough the push isn't there.

Suggestions? As an aside, I am not an a Mac and I know there are issues with pushing to Azure from a Mac.

UPDATE: Fixed the issue by deleting and redeployed the Azure instance. Ok for dev not so good for prod.

Comment: Have you tried using `git checkout -f` on the Azure side to force it to check out the latest version? I've run into issues like this on personal projects where it will receive the update but not actually check it out.

Comment: Ok so I just cloned from azure and the content is right. So, it looks Azure's deployment script didn't run?

Comment: Yep, sounds like the same issues I had - hooks weren't running properly when I pushed. Unfortunately I never fixed it, but I wish you luck.

Comment: @Chris Hayes well I suppose I could just hose the Azure side, since it is just a dev environment

Comment: If you hit this again, please try steps in https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-issues. Also, you can start a discussion on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/threads. We should get to the bottom of it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same issue and it would suck to have to delete my repo just to force azure to pick up a redeployment

Answer (score 1):

Did you push to the right remote? It sounds like you have two remotes (you can check with `git remote -v`) and you are pushing the non-azure one.

Another thing might be the branch, are you on a branch that is not `master`, but azure expects the deploy to happen on the `master` branch?

From your comment: The deployment script might not have run. You can either create a dummy commit or force pushing by `git push -f` to make the remote repository receive the content again.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response I am pushing to the right remote. I cleverly called it 'azure' to keep track. And I am pushing from master to master.

Comment: It did show the first push go through but the changes don't show and no deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, so I'll post my solution here in this old question in case it helps anyone.

I was posting to my GitHub repository but Azure suddenly wasn't picking it up for deployment any more.

I went into the repository on GitHub, then Settings -> Webhooks and Services, and noticed that the Azure webhook had a little red icon indicating a problem.  Clicking on it showed that GitHub was getting a 401 Unauthorised response from Azure.

Then I remembered Azure had sent me an email about a week ago saying my website was going to be moved to a new scale unit and my publishing profile would change.  I didn't think much of this at the time as I don't deploy with a publishing profile, but it looks like it also changed my deployment trigger URL.

I updated the GitHub Webhook with the new deployment URL (from the Configure tab of my Azure website) and it all works fine again.